# Dieudonne functor on truncated Barsotti-Tate groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X/k be a smooth scheme over a perfect field of characteristic p. Is the Dieudonne functor inducing an equivalence of categories between truncated Barsotti-Tate groups and truncated Dieudonne crystals (in the sense of de Jong)?